# Delete string in text file using Batch script

Tags: batch-file

I'm try to import a variable from a text file.
Settings.txt will have something like:

*Some settings* 
*Compiler="gcc"*
*Over settings*

Ideal what I would like to do is set gcc as a variable that can be called in a command later.
I couldn't work out how to do this so I decided to take the line and change it in an other text file and insert that into the variable.  Something like this:

```
SET config=
SET temp=
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('findstr Compiler: settings.txt') do set temp=%%x
echo %temp% > figcon.txt
type figcon.txt | findstr /v Compiler:
SET congif=<figcon.txt
echo: %config%
```

But that does not remove *Compiler:* from the text file.  Any advice you can offer, either how to specify what within the *""* as the variable, or how to delete a string from the text file would be very much a precipitated.
Many thanks

Comment: Your code will not return anything with the `Settings.txt` sample file you provided!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply `set` Directly the vars of your *setting.txt* like this :

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (setting.txt) do set %%a

echo Compiler value = %Compiler%
```

which will return `"gcc"` as value

With this first code **all** the value of your *setting.txt* will be setted.

**If you just need** `%compiler%`

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (setting.txt) do echo %%a | find /i "compiler" && set %%a

echo Compiler value = %Compiler%
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the interesting line in `Settings.txt` reads `Compiler: "gcc"`, use the following code:

```dos
for /F "tokens=2 delims=: " %%x in ('findstr /R /C:"^ *Compiler:" "Settings.txt"') do (
    set "Config=%%~x"
)
echo %Config%
```

(If the line of interest reads `Compiler="gcc"`, replace search string `^ *Compiler:` by `^ *Compiler=` instead.)

Here, the `tokens` and `delims` options of `for /F` are used to split the read string. The `~` modifier of the `for /F` variable removes the surrounding quotation marks, so variable `Config` will hold `gcc` finally.

The search string of `findstr` has been improved so that something like `MyCompiler:` does not constitute a match. Leading spaces are allowed; if you do not want that, change it to `^Compiler:` (or `^Compiler=`).

The `set` syntax has been improved to avoid trouble with potential special characters, the entire assignment expression is enclosed within quotation marks.

By the way: in your code you are using variable name `temp`; let me recommend not to do that, because this is a system-reserved variable containing a path pointing to the temporary directory.